# Django Templating Language objects comparison

Tags: django, django-models

I'm fairly new to Django. I have a database with `Events`. I want to display the name of the `Organisation` where `org_id` is the foreign key in the events model. My approach was to load in all the objects and then do some iterating through them but I get no output on the website. I feel like its got to do something with the templating language

models.py

```
class Organisation(models.Model):                      
   org_id=AutoSlugField(unique=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   email=models.EmailField(max_length = 250)

class Event(models.Model):
   event_id = AutoSlugField(unique=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   date = models.DateField()   
   event_category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   duration= models.IntegerField()
   org_id = models.ForeignKey(Organisation,on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
   maxparticipants= models.IntegerField()
   teacher_id=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

relevant snippet from event_details.html

```
<h3>Hosting Body</h3>
{% for org in orgs%}
    {%if org.org_id == event.org_id %}

        <p>{{org.name}}</p>

    {%endif%}
{%endfor%}
<h3>Date</h3>
<p>{{event.date}}</p>
```

views.py

```
def event_details(request,pk):
   event=Event.objects.get(event_id=pk)
   orgs=Organisation.objects.all()
   context={'event':event,'orgs':orgs}
   return render(request,'event_details.html',context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can render the relevant organization with:

```
<h3>Hosting Body</h3>
<p>{{ event.org_id.name }}</p>

<h3>Date</h3>
<p>{{ event.date }}</p>
```

You can boost efficiency by fetching the `Event` and `Organisation` data in the same query with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def event_details(request, pk):
   event = get_object_or_404(Event.objects.select_related('org_id'), event_id=pk)
   context = {'event':event}
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `org`, instead of <s>`org_id`</s>.

Comment: Thanks! This is my school project so I don't think I'll need to be very efficient with anything XD.  Again, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

in your template change it to:

```
<h3>Hosting Body</h3>
{% for org in orgs%}
    {%if org.org_id == event.org_id.org_id %}

        <p>{{org.name}}</p>

    {%endif%}
{%endfor%}
<h3>Date</h3>
<p>{{event.date}}</p>
```

Comment: Please *don't*: this will take linear time. If the number of organizations grows, it will result in huge amounts of data being transferred from the database to the application layer, and a template engine that is rendered unresponsive.

Comment: That is true and I just saw your answer which is obviously more optimised approch.

Comment: This seems a bit redundant since you would be accessing the Organisation entry through even.org_id.org_id anyway